# Can Facebook apps simply never be submitted for a review to keep then hidden?

Tags: facebook

At work, we've developed a Facebook app to create a configurable 'tab' page with live information from our API, so that a small handful of our partners can display it on their Facebook pages in a template we provide. The app works fine, but is not something that needs to be independently discovered by people browsing a list of Facebook apps.

Thus, my question is, do we ever need to submit this app for a formal review by Facebook, if we don't care about being listed in their app index? We've got the app URL that we're giving partners directly to install, and that's worked already.

I've provided as much of the app details as are required (descriptions, icons, privacy policy URLs, contact details etc) to meet Facebook's own requirements. Is there any chance Facebook will look at the app down the line and require a submission, considering the app now has 'users' (i.e. people that have viewed the tab page it creates).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something that can only be answered by Facebook.

Comment: @LennartRegebro I'm not sure how to ask Facebook directly this question for them to answer. I posted here, since their own support section links back here: https://developers.facebook.com/support/. I'm  hoping other developers might have run into a similar situation and can provide input.

Comment: You _only_ have to get your app reviewed if you want it to be listed in the app center – but it’s absolutely not mandatory. But be aware that people could possibly find your app in other ways, f.e. it might show up in the normal search under it’s name.

Comment: Thanks, @CBroe, it looks like I'm good then. I don't mind people accidentally finding it, since it needs to be configured with API credentials that they can only obtain from us. (feel free to add this as a full blown answer too, and I'll choose this as the accepted answer).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about facebook policy. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *only* have to get your app reviewed if you want it to be listed in the app center – but it’s absolutely not mandatory.

But be aware that people could possibly find your app in other ways, f.e. it might show up in the normal search under it’s name.

Comment: I think you also need to have it reviewed if you want "stories" or other publish rights for your app, is it ?

Comment: @adrianTNT: For anything that has to do with Open Graph actions you will need review of those as well, that is true (although it is a different “kind” of review, that is triggered specifically from the dashboard section where you define those). For simple publishing of posts/status updates/pictures/…, no review is needed.

Comment: A quick question: when Facebook asks for a "test user" in the review process, do they want the user id or user email of a test user ? I keep getting rejected because of this.